# How to Set Color of Column Graph On Click in amCharts?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to change color of selected column in a column graph (built using amCharts).

I have an event listener in place like this:

```
function handleClick(event) {

        event.item.graph.backgroundColor = "#3C3C3C"; // NOT WORKING
        display_value = event.item.graph.valueField + ": " + event.item.category + ": "  + event.item.values.value;
        console.log(display_value);

}
chart.addListener('clickGraphItem', handleClick);
```

This didn't work and I couldn't find any related example. I saw an example for Maps, but chart objects work differently.

Please siggest

Comment: What kind of amCharts you are using? charts/ Stock charts/ Map?        Provide some more code to have a better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to access the SVG element directly and change it's fill/stroke color, access like following within your event callback

```
event.item.bulletGraphics.node
```

http://codepen.io/amcharts/pen/3abea07c9fd4c1f44d3523d3dd80d489

Comment: Tried this. Getting bulletGraphics object as undefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please add it to your answer so that it is easy for future lookers to find.